# Setting a disk space quota on a samba share residing on an ZFS pool

Tags: centos, permissions, disk-usage, zfs, quota

I have several samba shares, one of which is used for storing some backups.

I want to set a disk space quota on said share, as the ZFS volume the share resides on is huge and multi-purpose... I don't want the backups taking up more than 20Tb.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how I can achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set the quota for a filesystem:

```
zfs set quota=20TB poolname/backup-filesystem
```

To query the current quota setting:

```
zfs get quota poolname/backup-filesystem
```

Note that quotas can only be set on ZFS filesystems (i.e. made with `zfs create pool/fsname`), not on subdirectories (made with `mkdir`).

subdirectories of a ZFS filesystem are included within that filesystem's quota usage.  Child filesystems inherit their parent's quota (if any) unless overridden with their own `zfs set quota=size pool/parent/child` command (but this is an additional restriction - child filesystems, like snapshots, are included in the parent's total quota usage).

Comment: Thank you cas - not only did you give me the exact answer I needed, you steered me away from the next pitfall. big thanks!